# Accuracy decrease when increasing K-Fold splits

Tags: python, prediction, k-fold

I'm using a Logistic Regressor and a Random Tree Forest Classifier to predict some values.

I implemented a Stratified K-Fold Cross Validation and I calculate the Accuracy of the two models.
When I use the K-Fold Split=3 I have better Accuracy than when I use the K-Fold Split=5.

I find it hard to believe that less values in training give better accuracy than having more values.
Is it possible?

I already checked the Accuracy calculation and the correctness of the input data.
Moreover, I calculate the accuracy of every split and the standard deviation of those accuracy. The standard deviation increases with the increase of the splits.

Comment: I think you misunderstood how the call works. kfold = 3 will use 2 folds for training and 1 fold for validation. So if you have 90 samples, 60 samples will be used for training and 30 for validation. With kfold=5, you will have 72 samples for training and 18 for validation. Plus the points in the validation folds are different between kfold=3 and 5 so you can not compare them directly.

Comment: Ok thanks!
But I do the loop for all the splits and I calculate the mean of the accuracy of these splits. So I should be able to compare these two values because in every case I predict all the 90 values, or am I wrong?

Comment: I use sk learn to stratify. I implemented the basic code, this one:
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

And I think I always try to predict all the values thanks to that for, the only things that change are the data I use for training and the data I use for test every loop

Comment: You should not be using the training data to measure how good your model is performing. Only use the keft out fold for this purpose. And since in the 2 cases (KFOLD=3 and 5), the training examples are different, it wont be an apples to apples comparison.